# Tkinter SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: state (how to make a button one time clickable?)

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax-error, keyword-argument

```
from tkinter import *



def Click():
    label = Label(root, text="You clicked it")
    label.pack()

root = Tk()
label2 = Label(root, text="You can only click one time")
Button = Button(root, text="Click me", padx=20, pady=20, state=NORMAL, 
command=Click,state=DISABLED)
Button.pack()
label2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Because I use state 2 times I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: state

How can I fix this error and make a button that can be clicked one time?

Comment: Disable the button it its click handler.

Comment: Can you explain it? I just started learning tkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. The idea is to update the button's `state` from within the `click` handler function.

FYI, star imports can cause trouble and are best avoided, so I've done that here. I've also changed some variable names to use lowercase, since capitalized names are typically reserved for `class` objects in Python (things like `Label` and `Tk`, for instance!)

```
import tkinter as tk


def click():
    label = tk.Label(root, text="You clicked it")
    label.pack()
    button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)  # disable the button here
    

root = tk.Tk()
label2 = tk.Label(root, text="You can only click one time")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", padx=20, pady=20, command=click)
button.pack()
label2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Bonus Round** - if you want to update the existing label (`label2`, that is) instead of creating a new label, you can also accomplish this with `config`

```
def click():
    label2.config(text="You clicked it")  # update the existing label
    button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)  # disable the button here
```

Comment: I tried code with label2 config and I got this error: " self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-class""

Comment: Can you show me how you're instantiating `label2` (how it's being created)? I can't reproduce that error with the code as-written.

Comment: I tried to pack it inside function too now I deleted that and it is fixed thanks

Comment: Ah, that'd do it!